# PHP calculator script

Tags: php, html, calculator

I've been looking all over for a sample script, but I haven't been able to find one.  Basically, I want to have the code get a value from a `div` and multiply that number based on the user input.  For example, if I have a site for recipes, and I want to have a calculator where the user enters the amount of servings that they need, and it'll change the recipe to give the amount of servings specified.  (you can see an example [HERE](http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Robbis-MM-Cookies/Detail.aspx).)

Comment: If you found an example, what is the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Does it have to be PHP? Do you know anything about PHP yet? Have you tried anything? Do you need help finding an example? Will you post the example if you find it?

Comment: thos values that are in the `div` on the example site are from a database

Comment: You have a history of vague questions that basically amount to asking someone to write a script for you. You usually get the best answers when you make a concerted effort to perform the task yourself, and ask a _specific_ question about a _specific_ aspect of the task about which you have a concern. This usually includes posting a stripped-down version of your own attempt, highlighting the specific line of code that isn't giving the results you expect. Usually, the very act of forming such a question reveals the answer before you even have to hit "submit". This is called debugging.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

To get the users input.

Then you can manipulate it according to your needs and then display it back to the users using [echo](https://www.php.net/echo)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can solve the problem with Javascript too !
if you are using PHP then do like this

```
if (isset($_POST['num1'],$_POST['num2'],$_POST['operator']))
{
 ...
}
```

if you do not use ISSET it will show warnings that $_POST is undefined or so...